# Facebook and twitter auto share to user account?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, social-media

I want to auto share a social media user account's from My iPhone application(without dialog box, cancel option , send option).how can I do.

Comment: It's Okay,what is wrong with my question,why are you decreased my point?

Comment: @H2CO3 you have no rights to comment on someone else like this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

instead of using dialog box, share your stuff using `doGraphPost`

Use this method to share on fb without opening dialog box

```
 <FbGraphResponse_Obj> = [fbGraph doGraphPost:@"me/feed" withPostVars:<NSMutableDictionary>];
```

Find here in detail:

```
// Invoke fbGraphCallback & prepare fbArray..

// preapare conent to be posted, add following snippet in same function

    NSMutableDictionary *variables = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:4];
    [variables setObject:@"Yours content to be shared" forKey:@"message"];


    // share prepared content to fb
    fb_graph_response = [fbGraph doGraphPost:@"me/feed" withPostVars:variables];
    NSLog(@"postMeFeedButtonPressed:  %@", fb_graph_response.htmlResponse);


where fb_graph_response is an instance of FbGraphResponse
```

Enjoy Programming!!